# Uploaded doc to SharePoint but want to keep original file on network up to date?

Tags: sharepoint, file, networking, storage

I have a file (word doc) on the network.  I upload this to SharePoint so that others can see and modify etc.  We have versioning (so we can track changes) and I check it out, make some adjustments and then check it in as a “major version”.  Now if I go directly to the file on the network – it doesn’t contain the changes made via SharePoint…  is it possible to get those changes “forced” back to the file on the network?

Whilst I understand the changes are stored in the SP SQL database the files on the network are considered our “master” copy which we’d like to have a separate instance of outside of SP for backup purposes.

I'm extremely new to SharePoint but I just can't seem to find a definite answer/solution to this problem, so any suggestions for how to achieve this (via SP 2007 or SP 2010, or even a 3rd party component) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that simply with out of the box components.

It sounds like you sort of want the functionality of a records management system, but using the network file system as the store.

- Possibly you could allow file access to the document library, they use a file sync tool (eg Sync Toy) to keep the file updated on the network.
- Or you could build a windows app/service to do the same thing, but using WebClient to download, then copy the document.
- Or you could build an event receiver, to upload the file to your network store.
- Or you could build a custom workflow action on publish, to upload it to the network.

Preferably, you should try to get the master document to be the document in SharePoint. It makes things easier when you stick to what the product can do.

Comment: I have found SP exposes sites in a windows explorer friendly location i.e. I open Windows Explorer and type in \\servername\DavWWWRoot\ I will be taken to the root of the SP site. This shows a list of all the folders\files that exist in the site and I can navigate to them as with any network location e.g. If I go to \\servername\DavWWWRoot\Docs\Documents I see the files that exist in the http:// servername/Docs/Documents/ SP Documents library. Using a standard xcopy command from the SP server to another location (on the network) provides a simple way of backing up the physical files.